# Wrong focus position in ContentEditable Div with placeholder in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a content Editable Div with a place holder.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkv9a2cu/4/).

```css
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
}

#myDiv {
  border: 1px dashed #AAA;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text here..."></div>
```

The problem is:
When we open this fiddle in Chrome and click on div we get cursor focus in div at center. see pic. below:

[image]

But when we do same thing in IE we get focus at last of place holder. see below pic.

[image]

I want to focus cursor at center in IE too.

Comment: I will add just one more issue here, if you open it in firefox, the border also will not get blue and the cursor is on the left side, at start of the textbox.

Comment: @Zorak yes it is in left side in firefox, is there any generic way to fix this for all browsers.

Comment: And you really need to use centered DIV? Why not to use textbox? Or if you need the content in div, you can define your div in jQuery and onclick geting its content, replace the div with textbox+button and the button will get again the content of textbox, removing it and replacing it by the div ... if this is acceptable, I can make a jsfiddle for you

Comment: I cannot change DIV :( @Zorak

Comment: Cannot change the div how? I made this fiddle including some jQuery and I think it works well https://jsfiddle.net/4pcpekj1/3/

Comment: One more edit, to remove outline for chrome, so except of the button, the user will not recognize the difference between div and input/button https://jsfiddle.net/4pcpekj1/5/

Comment: I cannot change DIV because this code is already live and there are so many other logics working on these DIVs (There are many of them), Changing them right now will not work for me. @Zorak

Comment: Did you looked at it? I am actually doing nothing to the DIV element except of changing its visibility, but the div stays here unchanged otherwise. It is only adding new elements into the structure and correct targeting via JS. Clean CSS cross-browser solutions probably does not  exist, because of different approach of browser engines to this, I am afraid. This is probably the best look-n-feel you can get right now :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why this happens, but you could apply `position: absolute;` to your pseudoelement and a few additional rules to size the div. This works for me in IE11.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/kskdpznk/1/)

Example:

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  position: relative;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  margin: auto;
}

#myDiv {
  border: 1px dashed #AAA;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text here..."></div>
```

Comment: this sadly does not work on FF. The cursor is moved away from the box

Comment: What if we want to change alignment to right with js? In that case placeholder will not move to right.

Comment: @Zorak I had a look on FF and yes I see the problem. It appears to be a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=904846

Comment: @Ajay I'm not sure of a cross browser solution in the scenario where you want to change alignment like that. It's quite specific. Best of luck